# Selection.MoveEnd not working while using Word Interop and C# to manipulate Word documents

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

I am developing a .NET program using VSTO 2010 running .NET 4.0 to find a specific subheading in a set of word documents and copy **all content under that subheading** (say "Requirements") using **Word.Interop**. I succeeded by means of a **for loop that matched words**, using which I search for this word and then the starting word of the next section (say "Functionality").

Now the documents also have a contents page so i found that **simple word matching wouldn't do** as it would return the first seen occurrence which was definitely in the contents section. So I tried finding the second occurrence an was successful but then realized that it could even be that the word might repeat itself much before the subheading. Hence I resorted to finding the sentence. here I was successful here in finding both the words (I had to modify the search string to "Requirements\r" because thats how it was being read)
Anyhow. The problem i am facing now is that after I get the starting and ending sentences, I **selected the entire document and using MoveStart and MoveEnd , i reduced down the selection before copying it and pasting it in another word document**,(as i dont know about using Range or Bookmark)
 However , while i was successful in moving the start and though the end position was correct, the **MoveEnd always moves to some text that is at least 10 sentences beyond the actual**. I've been at this for 2 weeks now and any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated. I dont mean any disrepect to all the programmers out there in the world. 
I've shown the code I'm using.

The variables used are self explanatory. 
//SourceApp and SourceDoc - Word application that reads source of release notes
//DestinationApp and DestinationDoc = Word application that writes into new document

```
    private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int startpos = findpos(SourceDoc, 1, starttext, sentencecount);
        int endpos = findpos(SourceDoc, startpos, endtext, sentencecount);

        object realstart = startpos - 1; // To retain the subheading
        object realend = -(sentencecount - (endpos - 1)); // to subtract the next subheading

        SourceDoc.Activate();
        SourceDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
        SourceDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.MoveStart(WdUnits.wdSentence, realstart);
        SourceDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.MoveEnd(WdUnits.wdSentence, realend); // the problematic bit
        SourceDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
        IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        string allText = data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();

        DestinationDoc.Activate();
        DestinationDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
        DestinationDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Delete();
        DestinationDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste();
        DestinationDoc.Save();

        ((_Application)SourceApp).Quit();
        ((_Application)DestinationApp).Quit();
        textBox1.AppendText(allText);

    }


    int findpos(Document docx, int startpos, string txt, int sentencecount)
    {
        int pos = 0;
        string text;
        for (int i = startpos; i <= sentencecount; i++)
        {
            text = docx.Sentences[i].Text;
            if (string.Equals(text, txt))
            {
                pos = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        return pos;
    }
```

I would also be extremely grateful if there was a way to extract specific subheading only (like 3.1 , 5.2.3 etc.) which is what I'm trying to achieve. The question is just my way of doing things and I'm open to a better way as well. 
Many thanks in advance.